# How to make an Iterative loop in Map<Pair<Match,DatapathId>, FlowRuleStats>?

Tags: java, dictionary, google-floodlight

I work on floodlight controller. I have a map as
`Map<Pair<Match,DatapathId>, FlowRuleStats>` 
and I just have `DatapathId`.

Here is some my code :

```
Map<Pair<Match,DatapathId>, FlowRuleStats> getFlowStats();
Map<Pair<Match, DatapathId>, FlowRuleStats> m;
m = switchStatistics.getFlowStats();
```

How can I make a loop and process all the element in the `m`?

Answer (score 0):

The map is keyed on `Pair<Match, DatapathId>` and evidently you don't have that. You only have DatapathId. Which means you can't do key based lookups. at all.

The only thing you can do is loop through the *entire* map:

```
for (var entry : m.entrySet()) {
    if (!entry.getKey().getRight().equals(datapathidYouHave)) continue;
    Pair<Match, DatapathId> md = entry.getKey();
    FlowRuleStats stats = entry.getValue();
    .....
}
```